# Не устанавливается dotnet в ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: c#, linux, .net, ubuntu

Использовал команду sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic, пишется в конце установки "dotnet-sdk 7.0.302 от Microsoft .NET Core (dotnetcore✓) установлен", но когда ввожу dotnet --version или dotnet new console (в vscode) появляется вот это:

The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

- You intended to execute a .NET application:
  The application '--version' does not exist.
- You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
  No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

Comment: неправильная опция `--version`

Comment: а какая правильная? И почему тогда при вводе dotnet new console в vs code пишется тоже самое?

Answer (score 0):

Я проверил прямо сейчас на Ubuntu-22.04 инструкцию https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap:

```bash
$ sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic --channel=7.0
[sudo] password for user:
dotnet-sdk (7.0/stable) 7.0.302 from Microsoft .NET Core (dotnetcore✓) installed
$ which dotnet
/snap/bin/dotnet
$ sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet
$ dotnet --version
7.0.302
```

Как видите, работает.

НО! `dotnet new console` завершился с `Segmentation fault`

Поэтому я снёс `snap` и [установил скриптом `dotnet-install`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual):

```
$ sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk
$ wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh
$ bash ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.dotnet
$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.408
 Commit:    0c3669d367

Runtime Environment:
...
$ dotnet new console
The template "Console App" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
...
$ ls
Program.cs  example.csproj  obj
```

Если вам нужем именно dotnet-7, то вместо `bash ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest` используйте команду `./dotnet-install.sh --channel 7.0`

Comment: ну, надёжнее всего архив развернуть в своем домашнем каталоге и переменные прописать  export DOTNET_ROOT=/home/***/dotnet7
export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools